# Lookup by Arc.container().instance using TypeLiteral not working (quarkus)

Tags: cdi, quarkus

I try to look up bean programatically using ArC.

I built the following:

```
public class ServiceLookup {
    public static <T extends Service> T get(Class<T> clazz, JobType jobType){
        return Arc.container().instance(clazz, new SupportsJobType.Impl(jobType)).get();
    }

    public static <T extends Service> T get2(JobType jobType){
        return Arc.container().instance(new TypeLiteral<T>() {}, new SupportsJobType.Impl(jobType)).get();
    }
}
```

Following finds the bean:

```
Service serviceA = ServiceLookup.get(Service.class, JobType.A)
```

However, I don't want to pass the class so tried following which sadly does not find the bean.

```
Service serviceA2 = ServiceLookup.get2(JobType.A)
```

Any obvious mistakes?
I sticked to the example from https://programtalk.com/java-more-examples/io.quarkus.arc.InstanceHandle.get()/

project with reproducer code: https://github.com/syr/quarkus-resteasy-postgres/tree/cdi-factory

Comment: You can't possibly make `get2` work due to the nature of Java generics. Your `new TypeLiteral<T>() {}` is basically equivalent to `new TypeLiteral<Service>() {}`, which is practically equivalent to `Service.class`. You simply have to specify the bean type explicitly, there's no getting around that.

Comment: But shouldn't it work?...for example panache finder methods
`public static <T extends PanacheEntityBase> T findById(Object id) {...}`  can also be used without explicit typing by `Service s = Service.findById(1)`
Or where am I thinking wrong?

Comment: And also with explicit type parameter it does not find the bean:
```ServiceLookup.<Service>get2(JobType.A)```

Comment: No, it shouldn't work. It can't work and won't work. To lookup a bean, you have to provide a type and a set of qualifiers. You're not providing the correct type. Maybe you think you are, but in fact, you're not, because of erasure. The inferred (or explicitly provided) type argument doesn't survive to runtime.

Comment: OK, I was obviously not aware of the type erasure. So, unfortunately I don't see a way to make it less ugly than `ServiceLookup.get(Service.class, JobType.A)`